# How does TS select the wrong method signature?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using `sequelize-typescript`, a TS wrapper around Sequelize, a JS ORM.

Within that, there's the following declaration:

```
public static findOne<M extends Model>(this: { new (): M } & typeof Model, options?: FindOptions): Promise<M | null>;
public static findOne<M extends Model>(this: { new (): M } & typeof Model, options: NonNullFindOptions): Promise<M>;
```

The interface `NonNullFindOptions` is an extension of `FindOptions` with a property `rejectOnError`. Basically, you can say to `findOne` "return `Promise<Model | null>`" or "return `Promise<Model>` or throw:.

Great! So, if I pass in `NonNullFindOptions`, then TS should infer that I'm going to get a `Promise<Model>`.

When I pass in a literal object of this type, this is the behaviour that I see.

However, I have created a function with a return type of `NonNullFindOptions`. When I pass this in, the first signature is selected,

I have created a [TS Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=30&pc=61#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGKgCYHkAOZgD2IAzsgN4CwAUMsgO4AW0EAXMgEoQIFQYA8xMFFABzADTJBwkCIB81AL7VqEAB44eYZKEixEKAHJEDAVwA2Z9CGx5CJZGsjXSVm-iKlKNZFAgArLjAsEABRAFs8AE82ACMCAjMIOBBkAB9kEKgoHgBuRWUqNQ0oLW4SLUZmcLhgMwBJUgBeZAAKSEEAVWJoNilRAEo2IxBTC1dcd3tG2XIC2l8wEygUr1paSt82MnawLugFMWo1n39A4PCotiETCEPvBWQ4UmHRy0wJu2I8qgVv6gQzE9SABZAgYCBmcjIJRUf6A4ikAAiJjCYUis28OBMMTMwAQkjAcHw+Jg7xAED4wIcqicGBBYIhsjaDGAxC2yHJdBag2QVIeADJkGBIjgIAQYLyGWYJARbB4APxscZykg8gAK2TCrIpVPSIHMZlk31oWJxeIJRPNpOswR11Np9PBhuZrPZnO5bD5yEFwtF4slTplKrZyBeBuVk2I6s12spRqOyFNuPxgktJLJdscEGcAcZLpDZA5EC5PK9PpFYoloMDyFlkaV72DaVDxnDjcj0YIWu6cebGq7sd1HINM1WawWSxS-e7EAAdL5iAkAG4QFpkB5PXn9Y3Q-KwqhlQTIGDxNjT2PI1GRGbNS9o2fW7Dktf0JibKE7PZQNgAch-0IkXwAgQIJQgiYUrigG5oW3AoAHo4OQAB1Bh0TAJgHCyHh5X+DwtBiOBv2Qc8ezva9kFvFF70fW0Wg2CBqlqBoWj-fptyAA) which strips everything down to the bare minimum.

What am I missing here? Why does TS select the wrong method signature in the second case?

---

For the link-averse:

```
interface FindOptions {
  where: Record<string, string>
}

export interface NonNullFindOptions extends FindOptions {
  rejectOnEmpty: boolean | Error;
}

export const whereEmailIs = (testUser: string): NonNullFindOptions => {

  return {
    where: {testUser},
    rejectOnEmpty: true,
  } as NonNullFindOptions;
};

class Model { }

class Dummy {
  public static findOne<M extends Model>(this: { new(): M } & typeof Model, options?: FindOptions): Promise<M | null>;
  public static findOne<M extends Model>(this: { new(): M } & typeof Model, options: NonNullFindOptions): Promise<M>;
  public static findOne<M extends Model>(this: { new(): M } & typeof Model, options: FindOptions | NonNullFindOptions): Promise<M> | Promise<M | null> {
    return Promise.resolve({} as M);
  }
}

const foo: Promise<Dummy> = Dummy.findOne({ where: { testUser: '' }, rejectOnEmpty: true });

// Why the error?
const bar: Promise<Dummy> = Dummy.findOne(whereEmailIs(''));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In order for the compiler to pick the correct type check, it follows a similar process to the underlying JavaScript. It looks at the overload list and, proceeding with the first overload, attempts to call the function with the provided parameters. If it finds a match, it picks this overload as the correct overload. For this reason, it’s customary to order overloads from most specific to least specific.

[From the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads).

`NonNullFindOptions` satisfies `FindOptions`, so Typescript is able to call the first method with a `NonNullFindOptions`, and thus selects it as the matching signature. Reversing the declaration order of your methods fixes the issue:

```
class Dummy {
  public static findOne<M extends Model>(this: { new(): M } & typeof Model, options: NonNullFindOptions): Promise<M>;
  public static findOne<M extends Model>(this: { new(): M } & typeof Model, options?: FindOptions): Promise<M | null>;
  public static findOne<M extends Model>(this: { new(): M } & typeof Model, options: FindOptions | NonNullFindOptions): Promise<M> | Promise<M | null> {
    return Promise.resolve({} as M);
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! I can confirm that changing the order helps. However, why does `foo` work, then? What is the difference between an explicit literal and a variable of the same value and type?

Comment: I've created https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35472 in case the difference in behaviour is a bug.

Comment: I'm not sure why `foo` works. If you pull the literal argument out into a variable or add a typecast, Typescript complains about it.

Comment: Turns out [Freshness](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/freshness.html) comes into play. Literal objects cannot be upcast whereas non-literal objects can and will be, when it comes to selecting method signatures.